# C++ Memory Leak With STL Vector

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks, stl, valgrind

I am building a templated Max Heap class in C++ for a datastructures class. The implementation demonstrates a Max Heap with a vector under the hood. There is an online submission associated with the assignment and when I submit mine, all the tests (push, pop, top, and size) pass and work (for the online unknown unit tests as well as all the ones I wrote) and I have no memory leaks with any of my tests, however I am failing the memory leak section with the online submission, indicating to me that my Bubble Up (Reheap Up) or Bubble Down (Reheap Down) algorithms are doing something funny with vector indices.

I noticed that I used the bracket operator a lot to mess with the vector, so I went through and changed all the brackets to `.at()` so I could see any suppressed out of bounds errors. Flying colors again, except for the memory leaks allegedly. I then figured well maybe one of the unit tests is adding sooo many values the vector fails to clear them all for some unknown reason...wasn't the case because I added so many values to a vector in my max heap class in my unit tests it took 90 seconds to finish and after all 52K allocations were made 52K deallocations were made as well and valgrind reported no errors.

Below is some of the main code for the class, if anyone could decide where some code is written that in some situation may warrant a memory leak that would be great!

```
template <class T> 
class MaxHeap {
public: 

MaxHeap(){ 
  // TODO: Fill me in
}

~MaxHeap() {
  data.clear();
}

void push(T value){
  data.push_back(value);
  bubbleUp(data.size()-1, value);
}

void pop(){
  if(!size()) {
    return;
  }
  T val = data.at(size()-1);
  data.pop_back();
  if(!size()) {
    return;
  }
  data.at(0) = val;
  bubbleDown(0, val);
}

T top(){
  if(!data.size()) throw logic_error("Empty Heap");
  return data.at(0);
}

unsigned int size(){
  return data.size();
}

void print_vec() {
  for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
    cout << data.at(i) << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}

vector<T> getVec() {
  return data;
}

private:
  vector<T> data;
  void bubbleUp(int idx, T value) {
    int position = idx;
    int parent_idx = parent(position);

    while (data.at(parent_idx) < value) {
      data.at(position) = data.at(parent_idx);
      data.at(parent_idx) = value;
      position = parent_idx;
      parent_idx = parent(position);
    }
  }

  void bubbleDown(int idx, T value) {
    int left_child_idx = left_child(idx);
    int right_child_idx = right_child(idx);
    int max_child_idx;

    if(left_child_idx <= size()-1) {  // left child (consequently right child) in bounds of vector
      if(left_child_idx == size()-1) { // no right child, left is maxchild
        max_child_idx = left_child_idx;
      } else {
        max_child_idx = (data.at(left_child_idx) <= data.at(right_child_idx)) ? right_child_idx : left_child_idx;
      }

      if(data.at(idx) < data.at(max_child_idx)) {
        data.at(idx) = data.at(max_child_idx);
        data.at(max_child_idx) = value;
        bubbleDown(max_child_idx, value);
      }
    }
  }

  int left_child(int idx) {return (idx*2+1);}
  int right_child(int idx) {return (idx*2+2);}
  int parent(int idx) {return ((idx-1)/2);}

};
```

Comment: If you don't do `new` and you use only `std::vector` and primitive types, then this code is not the source of the leak. However, `T` might be, and you do not control it here.

Comment: you are not using new or malloc in this code. is this the full code?

Comment: Exactly @Elazar T is a string in some of the online unit tests I know that much but I don't get what else I could be doing to remedy this. All allocated primitives and strings should be getting their memory returned back to the OS yet it seems its not

Comment: @DomFarolino I think you need to post what `T` is when you see these leaks.  Just describing that it is "a string in some online unit tests" doesn't convey what it really is.  I could easily come up with a "string" class that may look ok, but is disastrous when used in a vector.  If it were `std::string`, then that's one thing, but if it's something else, we have no idea of whether it has correct copy semantics (which is a requirement if you place an item in a vector and not have memory related issues).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie @Elazar So here was the problem. My unit tests, to ensure I my "heap" was really a heap, used `std::is_heap` to test the vector after every push and pop operation. This compiled correctly on my end, unit tests passed no errors or anything. However on the online computer, `c++11` (`std::is_heap` requires c++11) was not supported and for whatever reason my unit test that inserted tons of random values and checked `std::is_heap()` every step of the way was creating a memory leak when and only when `std::is_heap` was not declared, namely when `c++11` was not supported.

Comment: No memory leak on my machine, because all of my self-written unit tests run smoothly on my machine. They don't on the remote machine that grades the code (my professor's hidden unit tests run fine too, so safe bet he doesn't use `std::is_heap` for any checking, or anything requiring `c++11`).

Comment: @DomFarolino The bottom line is that the way your code uses `std::vector` is ok.  It doesn't use pointers explicitly, no calls to `new`, and you're using `at()` to check for boundary errors.  So the problem is not with the code you posted *unless* your `T` is not correct.  Why not post what `T` is?  It will be obvious right away to us if it will cause leaks or not without having to run it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie for all the T I use its fine. Professors unit tests online are hidden, we only see the results of the tests. He could be using any T that supports comparison operators

Comment: @DomFarolino If the assignment requires you to use `std::vector`, and you don't know what types are being sent, and the only thing you know about `T` is that it has `operator <`, then you're stuck.  So the professor is sending you `T`'s that are not amenable to vector's copy semantics -- plain and simple.  The `vector` itself has no memory leaks.  It is the professor's class that is leaking memory since it has not implemented the correct copy semantics.  If you have standing, I would bring this up to him / her and get more information on what can be assumed of the type.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The professor's unit tests are passing no problem. The problem lies when the grading server tries to run my unit tests. The unit tests fail on the grading server, but not my machine. This is because the grading server does not support `c++11`, and consequently `std::is_heap`, which I used often. For some reason, the unit test failing results in a random memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

*Warning*: this is only a theory, since it is improbable that the source of leak is in the code shown here.

If `T` is a malformed type, that does not release it's memory when using the assignment operator, then this might be the part that trigger this bad behvior:

```
T swap; // initialized to something. perhaps using new

while (data.at(parent_idx) < value) {
  swap = data.at(parent_idx); //assume no delete in T.operator=()
  data.at(parent_idx) = value;
  data.at(position) = swap;
  position = parent_idx;
  parent_idx = parent(position);
}
```

This is not a problem in *this code*. However, you might still be able to patch it here. Why is `T` defined outside the loop?

```
while (data.at(parent_idx) < value) {
  T swap = data.at(parent_idx); // no assignment here
  data.at(parent_idx) = value;
  data.at(position) = swap;
  position = parent_idx;
  parent_idx = parent(position);
}
```

===

Unrelated but better - don't use the unnecessary intermediate variable, and mix in move semantics:

```
while (data.at(parent_idx) < value) {
  data.at(position) = std::move(data.at(parent_idx));
  data.at(parent_idx) = value;
  position = parent_idx;
  parent_idx = parent(position);
}
```

Comment: I changed some of the code to look like your second block up there and re-wrote the bubble down function because it was not consistent with the bubble up. Anyways I implemented the things above (without `std::move`) and the latest code still gives errors Perhaps I'll try the `std::move`

Comment: A type that does not implement assignment operator correctly, has little chance to implement move semantics correctly...